# how can I test for SIGALRM in a except

Tags: python-2.7, signals

I'm using the SIGALRM signal to set a timeout within a function.  I have that working from some of the other posting but now I want to distinguish when the SIGALM causes the exception versus if another exception occurs.  I want this because the actual function will be called from another module using subprocess.Popen.  What I want is to send one return code back to the calling module if there is a timeout and a different code if it's some other exception.  This is the stripped down submodule:

```
import sys
import time
from signal import alarm, SIGALRM, signal

def other_handler():
    sys.exit(1)

def timeout_handler():
    sys.exit(2)

signal(SIGALRM,timeout_handler)
try:
    alarm(10)
    time.sleep(5)
    raise Exception('problem')

except:
    if SIGALRM:
        timeout_handler()
    else:
        other_handler()
```

So, in the code above I would expect other_handler() to get called but if I changed the code to be alarm(2) I want timeout_handler() to get called.  However right now regardless of what causes the exception timeout_handler() is run.

So what is the best way to distinguish between the SIGALRM exception and any other exception?

Comment: The only signal that causes an exception is `SIGINT`, and that's only for convenience, not because that's how signals should be handled.

Comment: I don't understand your comment.  When the alarm(x) reaches it's limit, an exception is thrown and the except code is executed.

Answer (score 0):

I see what  Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams comment means now.  I was fooling myself by putting the call to timeout_handler() in the except.  It isn't calling the exception but the signal() is directly calling the handler.  So the code should be the following and does that I'm trying to accomplish.  If x < y, the timeout_handler() is getting called by signal() and if x > y then I reach my exception and that causes other_handler() to get called from the exception handling.

```
import sys
import time
from signal import alarm, SIGALRM, signal

def other_handler():
    sys.exit(1)

def timeout_handler():
    sys.exit(2)

signal(SIGALRM,timeout_handler)
try:
    alarm(x)
    time.sleep(y)
    raise Exception('problem')

except:
    other_handler()
```